# Googlecast Custom Layout

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, android-cast-api

I'm planning to develop a googlecast application using android. But i'm wondering if we can use custom receiver that has a video and a `layout` that displays text from the android application, i have looked everywhere but i couldn't find anything related to my question. is this achievable:

1. is this achievable using android without using custom receiver.
2. is this achievable by only using custom receiver that displays
   lets say ( half of the screen video and the other half custom layout
   that receives data from android device) .

if there is any tutorial or any guide on how to implement this if possible please do point me to the right track.

P.S: i have searched for such thing but zero results i found.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a custom receiver; a custom receiver has some cast related stuff but it is simply an html page so you can layout the way you want. You can look at our [documentations](http://developers.google.com/cast) and [samples](http://github.com/googlecast).

Comment: in the documentation, there is no such thing mentioned that we can use custom layout like having half screen video and the other half some text that received from android application. for example: the docs mentioned that have have background,video,logo and water mark. that is all.

Comment: Documentation is not going to spell out everything that an html page can do; it states that a custom receiver is an html page with css and javascript,  (so is the default/styled receiver)) so I don't think you should expect it to exactly say you can have a half page video and half page something else, or 1/3 page video and 2/3 page something else, etc. It is an html page!

Comment: Hahaha. True that. But it can state the possibilities because when reading i thought it only accepts what its written.